# Async Twitch сhatbot with Python: socket, asyncio

Tags: python, sockets, chatbot, python-asyncio

I'm working on a twitch chat bot for my channel. Sync version of the bot works ok and I tried to write a simple async code with two tasks: reading the chat and responding on messages.

I'm not really experienced in Python and in asyncio in particular but basically as far as I know I want to 'await' all the i/o operations.

The problem is that the second task - the responding one - does not execute at all like it can't get the priority while reading task is waiting for receiving data.
It seems I don't understand some of the asyncio principles. Or maybe the socket can't work that way? Any help appreciated.

```
import socket
import asyncio

HOST = 'irc.twitch.tv'
NICK = 'rezolbot'
PORT = 6667
PASS = 'oauth:jhax3kh2i32vcg0hx00lw11r7mqk0d'
CHAN = 'rezolventa'

s = socket.socket()
mes_q = [] # queue of messages to send

# sync, only for connection
def send_line(line):
    s.send(bytearray(line, 'utf-8'))


# sends a message like it's from the bot in chat
async def send_message(message):
    s.send(bytearray('PRIVMSG #' + CHAN + ' :' + message + '\r\n', 'utf-8'))


# task, sends a message from a queue
async def respond():
    while True:
        if mes_q:
            await send_message(mes_q.pop(0))


async def listen():
    return s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')


# task parses messages from chat
async def fetch():
    while True:
        #await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        print('mes_q', mes_q)
        inc = await listen()
        print(inc)
        # append queue with last 3 symbols from incoming message
        mes_q.append('no you ' + inc[-5:-2])


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(fetch())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(respond())
    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    send_line('PASS ' + PASS + '\r\n')
    send_line('NICK ' + NICK + '\r\n')
    send_line('JOIN #' + CHAN + '\r\n')
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not asynchronous.
You're calling synchronous functions (`Socket.send`, ...) from a coroutine, which **does not make them asynchronous**. The functions themselves need to be coroutines.

[Here is a nice post explaining what a coroutine is and how it works](https://hackernoon.com/a-simple-introduction-to-pythons-asyncio-595d9c9ecf8c)

An example library you can use for opening a socket connection to twitch and performing asynchronous operations on it would be [websockets](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets).

If you want to write asynchronous chatbots in twitch, consider using something like [TwitchIO](https://github.com/TwitchIO/TwitchIO) to not hazzle around with sockets.

Also: You leaked your credentials, consider resetting them!